# use set find function, no operator found

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors, set, operators

I need your help to solve the next problem. So the problem is, when I use the find function on the set (data structure) I having the following problem (the .find make problem because one of the operators >,<,==).

> error C2679: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Item' (or there is no acceptable conversion

The lines in the code where the error happened -

```
if(items.find(itemList[option]) == items.end())
{
     items.insert(itemList[option]);
}
```

My operators (==,<,>)-

```
bool Item::operator<(Item& other) const
{
if (this->_serialNumber < other._serialNumber)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

bool Item::operator>(Item& other) const
{
if (this->_serialNumber > other._serialNumber)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

bool Item::operator==(Item& other) const
{
if (this->_serialNumber == other._serialNumber)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You can just `return this->serialNumber …` for your operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operators need to take their parameter by const ref:

```
bool Item::operator<(const Item& other) const
```

You can freely go from non-const to const, but not the other way around and `std::set` is trying to compare a const T.

P.S: You can shorten all of those to `return _serialNumber > other._serialNumber;`, no need for the if/else. It's shorter and clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I was stuck on it for long time